# Formula Field not visible in Layout

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field which , when I'm pulling to page layout is not showing up at all. i.e the field itself is not showing up ,let alone value.

Also  , when I'm querying the field in a controller , it's saying :
No such column 'ABCD__c' on entity 'PAC__c'.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like your **Field Level Security** (FLS) has not been setup correctly. Even though you made your field available on a page layout, the FLS must be enabled for your profile to be able to see the field on the page layout and on a query.

So have a look at the field again, click on button 'Set Field Level Security', enable it for your profile and you should be good to go!

Comment: That solved it . Should have thought about it in first place !

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permission to access that field. Go to create --> object --> Pac --> Select your field. Then Set Field-Level Security and make sure it is visible to your profile. Thanks